# What's the editor URL?

Tags: respondcms

This question may look funny, but: what's the URL to access the editor for an existing site?

I followed the installation instructions and the HTML5 settings, but I did not find any statement about the editor. I always get just to the 'create site' page.

Thanks for your support!
- Hardy

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's app.yourdomain.com/#/login/[site-name]

So, for example, your site name is ***test1***, then the login to the editor will be like app.yourdomain.com/#/login/test1

Hope this helps! :)